# Armor damage reduction system?

Tags: mathematics

So I want to develop a Dota2-like armor system where damage reduction never reaches 100%.

Armor values be like:

```
Armor --- Reduction

10 ---------- 10%

20 ---------- 19%

30 ---------- 27%

40 ---------- 35%
```

How to make something like that, where reduction never reachs 100%?

Comment: `damage = 150;` `damage -= 150 * (10/100);` => `Damage = 135`

Comment: i want a dynamic system where do i put armor value in your formula?

Comment: `ReductionDamage = Damage * ((100-Reduction)/100)`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is an increasing function that approaches a limit of 1 (for 100%).

There are infinite options to choose from here, but without further constraints we could pick a few simple ones:

```
// Scale the armor value to control how quickly it approaches the saturating value.
// fiftyPercentThreshold = the amount of armor you want to achieve 50% damage reduction
input = armor / fiftyPercentThreshold

// Simple ratio    
damageReduction = input / (input + 1.0)

// Arctangent
damageReduction = atan(input) * 2.0/PI
```

[image: Graph comparing ratio & arctangent methods]

Generally the positive half of any [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sum of a geometric sequence.

A geometric sequence has a starting value (\$a_1\$) and a quotient (\$q\$) and the n-th member is the multiple of the starting value and the quotient to the power of n:

$$a_n = a_1 \cdot q^n$$

The sum of the first n elementh of this sequence is

$$a_1 \cdot \frac{1 - q^n}{1 - q}$$

To make sure this doesn't go above 1 (100%), you need to make sure

$$\frac{a_1}{1 - q} $$

Doesn't go above 1 either

If you want the reduction the max out at 80%, then use 0.8